# Covering labels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am struggling with a problem regarding labels, namely wanting to cover them using Mask. Unfortunately I can't remove or block them, which causes a lot of extra work. The problematic issue is in screenshot 1 and the effect I want to achieve is in screenshot 2.

[image: screenshot no. 1][image: screenshot no.2]

I found some code on the QGIS forum that could probably help me, however I don't know Python. It's all about that label-covering effect. I have a lot of them and some of them are rule-based, so it takes a long time to set them manually.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import iface
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='custom')
def HideLabel(label,warstwa, feature, parent):
list_order = iface.layerTreeCanvasBridge().rootGroup().layerOrder()
list_of_layers_above = []
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer_position = lista_order.index(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(warstwa)[0])
for layer in lista_order[:layer_position]:
if layer.type() == QgsMapLayerType(1):
if root.findLayer(layer.id()).isVisible() == True:
list_of_layers_above.append(layer)
#if layer.type() == QgsMapLayerType(0) and layer.geometryType() == 2:
#if root.findLayer(layer.id()).isVisible() == True:
#list_of_layers_above.append(layer)
if len(list_of_layers_above) > 0:
wynik = ''
else:
result = label
print(result)
```

Comment: Could you use a rule based label to only draw the ones outside the mask?

Comment: I have several layers with several hundred sub-layers and each has a separate rule label, so such a variant for me is impossible.